# .net reference specificversion true or false?

Tags: .net, dll, reference

We are two companies who are working on the same project, in the same application. On a weekly basis we exchange **only** our assemblies (not the code) and reference each other's dll.

What is the best practice regarding the `specificversion` when adding reference to our project. 
Specifically, when should we use a `specificversion` value of *`true`* and in what case should we use *`false`*.

Comment: In general, it's good to reference precise versions of your dependencies, to guard against [software rot](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2011/6/28/the_new_heroku_4_erosion_resistance_explicit_contracts). That's why Ruby has `Gemfile.lock`, Python `requirements.txt` and Nodejs `npm-shrinkwrap.json`.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/24022135/284795 "One of the most important things to know is that SpecificVersion is a property that takes effect at compile-time and not at runtime."

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This answer is going to be based on the assumption that you are versioning your dlls.

If you set SpecificVersion to true (which is the default when adding a reference), then the project will reference to that dll with a particular version (say for instance 1.0.0.0).  If, at a later time, you're given a new dll (say 1.0.1.0), then you will have to remove the old dll reference and add the new reference.  This is because the project is specifically looking for 1.0.0.0 when you have a new version 1.0.1.0.

The alternative to this is to set the SpecificVersion to false, which tells the project to find the latest available dll and use that one.  The problem with this is that the project is now required to "hunt" in various places for the dll you've referenced, which can increase your build time.  It will do this even though it knows the path of the dll you've referenced.  I'm not sure if this is a bug or if this is done by design.  It might be checking to see if there are any newer dlls besides the one you've referenced (perhaps in the GAC or elsewhere).

Here's an [article](http://dvanderboom.wordpress.com/2007/12/11/visual-studio-2008-project-reference-oddness/) that describes this issue in more detail.

Comment: should we consider the assemblies coming from the other company loosely coupling version number ? I mean, is it a good practice to set the specific version to false and just drop the new dll (with a new version number) when weekly integration occurred ?

Comment: BTW, just read your reference on the article and gave me a lot of information. Thanks.