# .NET 4.0 XBAP security issues with GAC

Tags: wpf, gac, xbap

We have a problem since converting our products to .NET 4.0 and using the updated code access security model.  Basically we have component libraries that may or may not be installed to the GAC on a machine.

If someone makes an XBAP with default partial trust settings that uses these libraries and an end user installs the XBAP (which deploys the libraries during its install), it works fine if our libraries weren't already in the GAC.

If they were in the GAC, the XBAP will fail at run-time with security exceptions.  I believe the problem is due to this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970906.aspx

> When managed assemblies are installed into the global assembly cache (GAC), they become fully trusted because the user must provide explicit permission to install them. Because they are fully trusted, only fully trusted managed client applications can use them.

It seems that since they get pulled from the GAC, their security is elevated more even though they are the exact same .dlls deployed with the XBAP.  But in that case, everything breaks.

Is there any way to work around this issue short of adding the AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute to all the libraries?

Or is there a way to prevent an XBAP from looking in the GAC for an assembly and just using the exact copy of the reference it is deployed with?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio, solution explorer, click on the reference and try setting the property "SpecificVersion" to true. It should just look in the path specified and the version specified when referencing and not go hunting for the latest in the GAC.

See [.net reference specificversion true or false?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1063536/814871)

Note that if you add a new version of your reference, you'll have to remove your current reference, it won't automatically replace it.