# embedding microsoft interop dll into exe file

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating exe file of windows application using c# that creats a word application. I am targetting framework 2.0 and microsoft.interop.words ver 12. Problem is that client apllication having framework 4.0 and word 2010 installed have microsoft.interop.words ver 14.
Is ther any way I can embed above dll into exe file without using external tool or target to correct word dll version based on framework installed ??

Comment: High time you move ahead, using a 8 year old version of the framework doesn't make much sense anymore.  Being forced into this by a conflict with a programmer that isn't stuck like that isn't unusual.  This problem otherwise got cleanly solved in .NET 4 (and VS2010) with the Embed Interop Types feature.  No interop library required anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In the settings area in you project under references you can reference the dll and set it to copy local, or you could limit you application to only use .NET 2.0

Comment: Hi Thanks for update.. actually I have already restricted this to Net 2.0 and working fine on system with this configuration. But when i try to run on 4.0 framework having words 2010 > application try to look for microsoft.interop.words ver 12 which is not present as replaced by ver 14. I am suppose to pass only one .exe file to client

Comment: Okay , it's possible to set visual studio to only use a specific version of a dll see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063459/net-reference-specificversion-true-or-false)