# Bind to a specific assembly version from GAC

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, gac

We have a visual studio package (VS Package) that references two class library projects: Project A and Project B. Project A in turn references another class library project (Project B).

So the dependency structure looks like this: 
VS Package 
  -> Project A
  -> Project B

All projects exist inside the same solution and the dependencies have been set up as proper project references. When deploying the VS Package the assemblies from Project A and Project B are deployed to GAC. The assemblies are strong named. No binding redirection is specified.

We deploy several versions of the same VS package thus several versions of Project A and Project B assemblies are in GAC. The problem is that no matter which version of VS package is executed it always loads the latest assembly versions from GAC.

How can we force the correct version of the assembly to be loaded from GAC that is the version used when building the VS Package project?

Thanks.

Edited my original post to more accurately describe my situation.

Comment: Can you show the references in your question.

Comment: Can you be more specific on this?

Comment: You presumably have lines such as `<add assembly="..." />` in your web.config that reference the assemblies.

Comment: The assembly is referenced through a ProjectReference:<ProjectReference Include="..\foo\foo.vcs12.csproj">
      <Project>{2b48b2ba-6ea5-4b1d-a678-97dca29bd223}</Project>
      <Name>foo.vcs12</Name>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </ProjectReference>

Comment: That's just for Visual Studio. Somewhere the deployed site is telling the framework about the reference at runtime. Doesn't your web.config have any lines like I showed?

Comment: I don't have a web app. My application is a c# visual studio extension. I consists of three assembly files. The main assembly is loaded by visual studio. The other assemblies are deployed to GAC and used by the main assembly.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, thought you were asking about a web app for some reason. See my answer in that case.

Comment: Are you changing the assembly version on the different versions? The GAC's notion of versions only recognizes the assembly version.

Comment: Yes the version of the assemblies is changed. I can see the different assembly versions deployed in GAC.

Comment: Then this shouldn't happen unless you are specifically redirecting to a new version. Do you have a policy file or a binding redirect in your app.config?

Comment: No I don't have a binding redirect.

Comment: Are you building and deploying on the same machine? Is your question how to get Visual Studio/MSBuild to pick up the desired version when building or how to get the desired version used when running the application?

Comment: I am deploying a clean VM. My question is: When running the app I want to load the exact assembly version that was used during build.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick , but I cant recommend it you should avoid using the GAC and have your librarys close.

```
Assembly SampleAssembly;
SampleAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("c:\\Sample.Assembly.dll");
```

[For more information read the manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In the Properties window for the reference, you may set `Specific Version` to true.

[image]

Comment: That option is not available if you have a project reference.

Comment: For some reason the main assembly does not load from GAC the same assembly version that was used during the project build

Comment: "Specific Version" is enforced at compile-time, not run-time.

Comment: Given the issue you've encountered, you probably want to change it to a dll reference, which will give you the version control you seek.

Comment: @mike I agree, but how is this done for an assembly that is the output of a project.

Comment: @Ciprian You can't do it for a project reference because it doesn't make any sense. All "Specific Version" does is enforce that the version referenced in the proj file is the version used when compiling. Since the build system will look in several places for the assembly it may get the wrong one. Projects don't have versions. Assemblies do.

Comment: Yes, but what I thought the "Reference Output Assembly" option does just that, reference an assembly which happens to be the output of a project being built. May I'm wrong on this.

Comment: @mikez I think you may be mistaken? I've used `SpecificVersion` successfully to get an add-in to pick up the right version. Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063459/net-reference-specificversion-true-or-false)

Comment: @Ciprian to use a dll reference instead of a project reference, when adding a reference use the browse button to find the dll in the project bin folder (or preferably in a more controlled location where you've decided to keep the required version).

Answer (score 0):

You may add a `Binding Redirect`. This can be done at various levels such as machine, app, or by a publishing policy.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx) for guidance.